# Jupyter throwing an error on basic for loops?

Tags: for-loop, jupyter

Relatively new to python.
I'm using basic for loops and list comprehensions, and I keep getting this error with Jupyter notebooks that doesn't happen with normal .py files, which I've isolated down:

```
for x in range(6):
  print(x)
```

I get the following error in Jupyter

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-78447d29c240> in <module>
----> 1 for x in range(6):
      2   print(x)
      3     # df.loc[df['date'] == '2000-01-0{}'.format(x)]

TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

Which doesn't happen with .py files running in VS Code or PyCharm.

I'm using anaconda, tried

`conda update --all`

It throws the error with for loops and when I use a for loop in a list comprehension, again only in Jupyter.  Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: Definitely the problem is not that bit of code, might be manifesting at that point but it is somewhere else

Comment: Did you earlier in the notebook define `range` as something else?

Answer (score 1):

There might be some problem with the Kernel.
In Jupyter main menu:

1. Kernel -> Shutdown 2) Kernel -> Restart